# How to plot 3D graphs with ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am running the following example from this [blog post](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/11/3-d-plots-with-plotly.html)
to draw a 3D chart. The code runs without any errors but the output is not as expected.
Here is the code

```
library(plotly)
pp <- function (n,r=4) {
    x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n)
    df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
    df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
    df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6)
    df
}
qplot(x, y, data=pp(100), geom="tile", fill=z)
ggplotly()
```

And here is what I would expect
[image]

Comment: Please define `py`. I'm guessing you just want to run `ggplotly()` instead.

Comment: What seems to be wrong with it? Does it generate an error? If so, what does the error say? Do you see a plot that doesn't look right? Does your R Session crash?

Comment: @Gregor Sorry it should be clearer now.

Comment: When I run your code I get a bunch of deprecation errors.  `plotly` is pretty fast-developing, the blog post is a couple of years old, presumably there is a new correct syntax for doing this ... ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed `plotly`, copied the code from your question and it ran perfectly fine. But it does indeed not return the 3D plot that you attached. The reason is that now `ggplolty()` takes your ggplot and "transforms into a plotly plot". The example given in the blog-post is most likely depreciated, as B. Bolker is saying in the comments.

There is however an upside to this. `plotly` does still have options for surface plots (see: [plotly-documentation](https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/#3d-surface-plots-in-r)). This means that you can recreate the example with the following code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)
#
pp <- function (n,r=4) {
    x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n)
    df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
    df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
    df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6)
    df
}
data_xyz <- pp(100)
data_z <- acast(data_xyz, x~y, value.var = "z")
plot_ly(z = data_z,  type = "surface")
```

Comment: If I correctly understood the blog post I linked, that's actually the output that I should have by running that code.

Comment: @Dambo Hey, thank you for the clarification. Please see my edited answer. I hopeit tells you what you wanted to know! Tell me if so =)

Comment: Thanks. For anybody who notices any discrepancies between the pic I posted and your solution: In the pic the graph is upside-down.